# Implementing Bind() (SelectMany in LINQ) without yield (in C++)

Tags: c++, .net, bind, linq

I'm trying to implement `Ana`, `Cata` and `Bind` (from [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-MinLINQ-The-Essence-of-LINQ)) in C++. I've managed `Ana` and `Cata`, but `Bind` eludes me.

Here's what I have for `Ana` and `Cata`:

```
#define FEnumerable function<function<Option<T>(void)>(void)>
#define TResult function<function<Option<R>(void)>(void)>

template<typename T> class Option {
public:
    bool HasValue;
    T value;
    Option(T value) : HasValue(true), value(value) { }
    Option() : HasValue(false) { }
};

template<typename T> FEnumerable Ana(T seed, function<bool(T)> condition, function<T(T)> next) {
    auto result = [condition, next, seed]() -> function<Option<T>()> {
        return [condition, next, seed]() -> Option<T> {
            static Option<T> value;
            value = Option<T>(value.HasValue ? next(value.value) : seed);
            if (condition(value.value))
                return Option<T>(value.value);
            return Option<T>();
        };
    };
    return result;
};

template<typename T, typename R> TResult Ana(T seed, function<bool(T)> condition, function<T(T)> next, function<R(T)> translation) {
    auto result = [condition, next, seed, translation]() -> function<Option<R>()> {
        return [condition, next, seed, translation]() -> Option<R> {
            static Option<T> value;
            value = Option<T>(value.HasValue ? next(value.value) : seed);
            if (condition(value.value))
                return Option<R>(translation(value.value));
            return Option<R>();
        };
    };
    return result;
};

template<typename T, typename A> A Cata(FEnumerable source, A seed, function<A(A, T)> fn) {
    auto e = source();
    A result = seed;
    Option<T> value;
    while ((value = e()).HasValue)
        result = fn(result, value.value);
    return result;
};

template<typename T, typename A, typename R> R Cata(FEnumerable source, A seed, function<A(A, T)> fn, function<R(A)> translation) {
    auto e = source();
    R result = seed;
    Option<T> value;
    while ((value = e()).HasValue)
        result = fn(result, value.value);
    return translation(result);
};
```

So far, I reckon I've done a decent job. The sequences are lazily-evaluated (something that would be trivial in .NET these days with the Yield keyword) and presumably lightweight. However, I just can't bend my head around the lambdas required for `Bind`:

```
template<typename T> TResult Bind(FEnumerable source, function<TResult(T)> selector) {
    ...
}
```

In other words, `Bind()` needs to accept an `FEnumerable<T>` (lazy sequence) and a selector function that accepts a single value and returns a sequence of values; and then Bind must call the selector function once for each input value, then return all the values returned by the selector in one big sequence. **But lazily.** As an `FEnumerable<R>`.

For reference, here's how it would look in C#, with yield:

```
foreach (var value in source)
    foreach (var result in selector(value))
        yield return result;
```

Yeah, it's a bit more difficult without yield. Here's how it would look in C++ without lazy evaluation:

```
list<R> results;
while ((auto value = source()).HasValue)
    while ((auto result = selector(value)).HasValue)
        results.push_back(result);
return results;
```

But I need lazy evaluation, which means nested lambdas. If anyone gets this far without his head exploding, please help me out.

Comment: How is a `FEnumerable` not just a `function<optional<T>()>`?  Is it that you want to be able to restart?  I guess that makes sense.  btw, `boost::optional` is moving into `std` in C++14.

Comment: FEnumerable is a function returning a function. In the same way that a std::list can give you an iterator, and the iterator can give you the values; you can ask the FEnumerable for its function value multiple times, and get different iterator instances.

Comment: @SodAlmighty I have a GitHub project **linq-cpp** that brings LINQ functionality to C++11. It looks like this is what you're trying to do as well (to some degree). Check it out and contact me if you're interested. https://github.com/timothy-shields/linq-cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to make a subsource, i.e. the successive results of `source` as we iterate over it, part of the closure state:

```
template<typename T>
TResult Bind(FEnumerable source, function<TResult(T)> selector)
{
    return [source, selector]() -> function<Option<R>()>
    {
        auto e = source();
        // Note that std::function is nullable and I am using
        // this possible state!
        // If this isn't std::function, making subsource an
        // Option<function<Option<R>()> is always a possibility
        function<Option<R>()> subsource;

        return [e, subsource, selector]() -> Option<R>
        {
            while(!subsource) {
                // This means we need to fetch a new subsource
                auto candidate = e();
                if(!candidate.HasValue) {
                    // Iteration ends here once `e` has run out
                    return Option<R>();
                } else {
                    subsource = selector(candidate.value)();
                }

                auto result = subsource();
                if(!result.HasValue) {
                    // We selected over an empty subsource, so let's
                    // try again and maybe pick a new fresh one
                    subsource = nullptr;
                    continue;
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Note that this relies on `e()` to be called repeatedly, assuming an empty `Option<T>` is returned each time once iteration has expired. Otherwise, you can encode the 'we've run out of sub-sources' state explicitly e.g. with one more closure variable.

Or maybe client code has the burden to stop iterating over the result of `Bind` once the end of iteration is reached, in which case you're good to go as well and the end of `source`/`e` will still only be reached once.

Comment: There are a couple of bugs - you forgot `mutable`, and your `while` block encompasses too much code, but it's close. I fixed them and it's working fine now. Many thanks! I'll accept your answer, but post a new answer with the fixed code for anyone else who wanders in.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I took the code from Luc Danton, fixed a couple of things and got it working. Here's the code for anyone else looking for the solution:

```
template<typename T, typename R> TResult Bind(FEnumerable source, function<TResult(T)> selector) {
    return [source, selector]() -> function<Option<R>()> {
        auto e = source();
        // Note that std::function is nullable and I am using this possible state!
        // If this isn't std::function, making subsource an Option<function<Option<R>()> is always a possibility
        function<Option<R>()> subsource;
        return [e, subsource, selector]() mutable -> Option<R> {
            while (true) {
                while(!subsource) {             // This means we need to fetch a new subsource
                    auto candidate = e();
                    if (!candidate.HasValue)
                        return Option<R>();      // Iteration ends here once `source` has run out
                    subsource = selector(candidate.value)();
                }
                auto result = subsource();
                if (result.HasValue)
                    return result;
                subsource = nullptr;        // We selected over an empty subsource, so let's try again and maybe pick a new fresh one
            }
            return Option<R>();
        };
    };
}
```